# Is it perfectly ok to use ReadLineAsync for client-server communication

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to implement client-server communication which should support commands ending with newline character. Is it perfectly ok to do something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RunServer();
    }

    async private Task RunServer()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1065);
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            HandleClient(client);
        }
    }

    async private Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
        {
            var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadLineAsync(); // here
            MessageBox.Show("Received \"" + dataFromServer + "\"");
        }
    }
}
```

or should I use `AsyncRead` and check whether received buffer contains '\n' character instead?

Will it work in any case, even if the message will be divided to several IP packets?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Any reason you're not using SignalR instead? SignalR is a couple of orders of magnitude easier to use than raw sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I think using ReadLineAsync over ReadAsync is better: you are reading a line and no need for extra if-statement, neither for an extra loop.

Comment: Will it work in any case, even if the message will be divided to several IP packets?

Comment: Can you give an example: it has been a long day so I might misunderstand it. You have a message which can have multiple lines with IP-addresses right? So you have 127.0.0.1\n127.0.0.2 (new lines not working in comments).

Comment: No. Suppose that the request "some_command\n" from the client will be divided for two packets (for example, "some_" and "command\n"). Will it work anyway?